# Drupal 7 multiple fieldset

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, cck

I want to make a custom type of node. In this one, some informations and the ability to link multiple documents (0->n documents). Until here no problem, I put an "unlimited" number of values.

Now, I have to attach one textfield with the documents. They both have to be "unlimited". How can I do that?

Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/field_collection is the more simple solution but I must confess that  this module sucks when you make a hard developement with it.